# TypeScript isolatedModules true export generator function

Tags: typescript, generator, redux-saga

I have a `index.ts` file that exports a generator function

```
export function* myFunction() { [...] }
```

It works fine with `--isolatedModules = false` but fails to compile with `--isolatedModules = true`

Error message during compilation:

```
All files must be modules when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.  TS1208
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> All files must be modules when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.  TS1208

This error happens when there is no `import` or `export` statement in a file (these make a file a module).

The example you provided will not result in this error. However where that error is occurring, just add an `export` or `import`.

Comment: You are correct, the error was happening in another file with the same name .... Will leave this question here nonetheless in case somebody else witnesses the same

Comment: @klugjo "another file with the same name" -- this comment was The Answer for me!

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to solve this is editing the `tsconfig` file to set `"isolatedModules": false,`

```json
"compilerOptions": {
  "isolatedModules": false,
}
```